# How to update value of each row in Table View of JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to create Table view which have dynamic column and rows so I want to update each cell value from the background as soon as I get the values from my data source like this which I used in swing `setValueAt()`.
So basically I don't want to create model class because my columns are not fixed and also the rows are not fixed and I don't want to recreate the table view to update one row in table view so please guide me because I am new to Table view of javafx. In case if you don't understand my question then please comment

Thanks

Edit example source code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.*;

public class DynamicTableView extends Application {

private static final int N_COLS = 5;
private static final int N_ROWS = 1000;

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    TestDataGenerator dataGenerator = new TestDataGenerator();

    TableView<ObservableList<String>> tableView = new TableView<>();

    // add columns
    List<String> columnNames = dataGenerator.getNext(N_COLS);
    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++) {
        final int finalIdx = i;
        TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> column = new TableColumn<>(
                columnNames.get(i)
        );
        column.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue().get(finalIdx)));
        tableView.getColumns().add(column);
    }

    // add data
    for (int i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i++) {
        tableView.getItems().add(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        dataGenerator.getNext(N_COLS)
                )
        );
    }

    tableView.setPrefHeight(200);

    Scene scene = new Scene(tableView);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

private static class TestDataGenerator {

    private static final String[] LOREM = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tempus cursus diam ac blandit. Ut ultrices lacus et mattis laoreet. Morbi vehicula tincidunt eros lobortis varius. Nam quis tortor commodo, vehicula ante vitae, sagittis enim. Vivamus mollis placerat leo non pellentesque. Nam blandit, odio quis facilisis posuere, mauris elit tincidunt ante, ut eleifend augue neque dictum diam. Curabitur sed lacus eget dolor laoreet cursus ut cursus elit. Phasellus quis interdum lorem, eget efficitur enim. Curabitur commodo, est ut scelerisque aliquet, urna velit tincidunt massa, tristique varius mi neque et velit. In condimentum quis nisi et ultricies. Nunc posuere felis a velit dictum suscipit ac non nisl. Pellentesque eleifend, purus vel consequat facilisis, sapien lacus rutrum eros, quis finibus lacus magna eget est. Nullam eros nisl, sodales et luctus at, lobortis at sem.".split(" ");

    private int curWord = 0;

    List<String> getNext(int nWords) {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nWords; i++) {
            if (curWord == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                curWord = 0;
            }

            words.add(LOREM[curWord % LOREM.length]);
            curWord++;
        }

        return words;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) says, the property that holds the table model is items. You can do:

```
table.getItems()
```

and work with it (add, remove, clear...).

As I see in your example you have a Table of Strings. In order to choose what is displayed on each column you have to use [setValueFactory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellValueFactory-javafx.util.Callback-). This way each column will know how to render each value. Let's say you have the String:

```
"Hi how are you?"
```

And you are trying to do get 4 columns like this:

```
hi | how | are | you?
```

You can just itetate over each column and set a cellValueFactory that splits the param.getValue() and takes its correspondent index.

**EDIT:** added your changeValueAt():

```
public class DynamicTableView extends Application {

private static final int N_COLS = 5;
private static final int N_ROWS = 1000;

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    TestDataGenerator dataGenerator = new TestDataGenerator();

    TableView<ObservableList<String>> tableView = new TableView<>();

    // add columns
    List<String> columnNames = dataGenerator.getNext(N_COLS);
    for (int i = 0; i < N_COLS; i++) {
        final int index = i;
        TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> column = new TableColumn<>(columnNames.get(i));
        column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>((cellData.getValue().get(index))));
        tableView.getColumns().add(column);
    }

    // add data
    for (int i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i++) {
        tableView.getItems().add(FXCollections.observableArrayList(dataGenerator.getNext(N_COLS)));
    }

    tableView.setPrefHeight(200);

    Scene scene = new Scene(tableView);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    changeValueAt(0,0, "thisIsMyNewValue", tableView);

}

private static void changeValueAt(int row, int col, String value, TableView<ObservableList<String>> table){
    ObservableList newData = table.getItems().get(row);
    newData.set(col, value);
    table.getItems().set(row, newData);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}

private static class TestDataGenerator {

    private static final String[] LOREM = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tempus cursus diam ac blandit. Ut ultrices lacus et mattis laoreet. Morbi vehicula tincidunt eros lobortis varius. Nam quis tortor commodo, vehicula ante vitae, sagittis enim. Vivamus mollis placerat leo non pellentesque. Nam blandit, odio quis facilisis posuere, mauris elit tincidunt ante, ut eleifend augue neque dictum diam. Curabitur sed lacus eget dolor laoreet cursus ut cursus elit. Phasellus quis interdum lorem, eget efficitur enim. Curabitur commodo, est ut scelerisque aliquet, urna velit tincidunt massa, tristique varius mi neque et velit. In condimentum quis nisi et ultricies. Nunc posuere felis a velit dictum suscipit ac non nisl. Pellentesque eleifend, purus vel consequat facilisis, sapien lacus rutrum eros, quis finibus lacus magna eget est. Nullam eros nisl, sodales et luctus at, lobortis at sem."
            .split(" ");

    private int curWord = 0;

    List<String> getNext(int nWords) {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nWords; i++) {
            if (curWord == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                curWord = 0;
            }

            words.add(LOREM[curWord % LOREM.length]);
            curWord++;
        }

        return words;
    }
}
```

}

The important thing is this:

```
private static void changeValueAt(int row, int col, String value,   TableView<ObservableList<String>> table){
    ObservableList newData = table.getItems().get(row);
    newData.set(col, value);
    table.getItems().set(row, newData);
```

}

The renderers are fired everytime the properties change. I just access to the element at the row you want to change and there I access to the element at the column. By changing it, the change is noticed to the column which renders the new value.

**EXPLANATION**

The generic class in the TableView represents the class of the generic type in the ObservableList the TableView holds (in the items property). This type coincides with the type of the row, so by doing:

```
table.getItems().get(0)
```

you are retrieving the object that holds the first row data, in your case an ObservableList. This is why your table.getItems() returns

```
ObservableList<ObservableList<String>>
```

(ObservableList of the generic type you provided).

While rendering each column you have to provide a CellValueFactory, indicating the TableView generic type and the column data type and then implementing how to get the cell value from the information you have.

All of this work with properties, that are like normal data types but fire events on change. That's why my method works, once you modify a property, this property fires the changed event and the table rerenders (short explanation). The thing here is that this changes don't get propagated so by changing a column, the list that holds the rows, each of wich hold the columns doesn't get notified. That's why I set the same row again once I have already modified it.

Just understand that your example is quite rare, as usually the table holds normal POJOs and the only ObservableList you interact with is the items property.

Comment: Thanks for answer but this is just the example which i grabed while searching for the solution My use case is completely deferent

Comment: i want somthing like the `setValueAt()` method of swing

Comment: Sorrry, I think I get what you want to tell but can't understand how should I implement it can you show me by editing above code if possible

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit and the example code I was trying to hard but can't get it even reading the documentation

Comment: so now I have to only call that changeValueAt() function every time to change the values of my table

Comment: @HemantSangle That's correct. But please try to understand what it's being done, so you will be able to do it again in other conditions. I'm adding a brief explanation on my answer. Feel free to ask.

Comment: Ohh Thanks for the detail explanation but I understand it on yesterday that I am getting the `ObservableList<String>` from the table view but not until you Edited my code so once more thanks for the edit

Comment: And let me tell you that I required this type of table view because I am working with the Modbus api and reading register values from the RS-485 enabled energy meter so to display the readings I wanted the table view that can be dynamically created on the basis of registers I have read from the meter

Comment: and how can I ping you personally on stackoverflow if I need any help

Comment: As far as I know you cannot, but just ask a well explained question and someone will answer you :)